# I need to hide declared objects in .kv file

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivy-language, python-class

I am developing an application to help children with functional diversity learn to read and write.

In the first activity of the app, children have to pop the bubbles of the letter indicated, for example, pop all the bubbles containing the letter "A". I have two problems, the first one is that I am not able to hide the bubbles that I have declared in the .kv, as you can see in the image, the bubble "Z" appears immobile in the lower left corner and I think that bubble appears because it is the last one that I have declared in the .kv.

The other problem is that I am not able to have more than one bubble with the same letter.

file.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('bubble.kv')

class BubblePop(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    
    def move(self):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
        
class BubbleGame(Widget):
    bubbleA = ObjectProperty(None)
    bubbleB = ObjectProperty(None)
        
    def serve_bubble(self):
        self.bubbleA.center = self.center
        self.bubbleA.velocity = Vector(1,0).rotate(randint(0,360))
        self.bubbleB.center = self.center
        self.bubbleB.velocity = Vector(1,0).rotate(randint(0,360))
        
        
    def update(self, dt):
        self.bubbleA.move()
        if (self.bubbleA.y < 0) or (self.bubbleA.top > self.height):
            self.bubbleA.velocity_y *= -1
               
        if (self.bubbleA.x < 0) or (self.bubbleA.right > self.width):
            self.bubbleA.velocity_x *= -1
            
        self.bubbleB.move()
        if (self.bubbleB.y < 0) or (self.bubbleB.top > self.height):
            self.bubbleB.velocity_y *= -1
            
        if (self.bubbleB.x < 0) or (self.bubbleB.right > self.width):
            self.bubbleB.velocity_x *= -1   
            
class BubbleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = BubbleGame()
        game.serve_bubble()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        
        return game
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    BubbleApp().run()
```

file.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.0

<BubblePop>:
    size: 100, 100

<BubbleGame>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'data/img/fondobosque.jpg'
    bubbleA: bubble_A
    bubbleB: bubble_B
    bubbleC: bubble_C
    bubbleD: bubble_D
    bubbleE: bubble_E
    bubbleF: bubble_F   
    bubbleG: bubble_G
    bubbleH: bubble_H
    bubbleI: bubble_I
    bubbleJ: bubble_J   
    bubbleK: bubble_K
    bubbleL: bubble_L
    bubbleM: bubble_M
    bubbleN: bubble_N
    bubbleNN: bubble_NN
    bubbleO: bubble_O
    bubbleP: bubble_P
    bubbleQ: bubble_Q   
    bubbleR: bubble_R
    bubbleS: bubble_S   
    bubbleT: bubble_T
    bubbleU: bubble_U
    bubbleV: bubble_V
    bubbleW: bubble_W
    bubbleX: bubble_X
    bubbleY: bubble_Y
    bubbleZ: bubble_Z
        
    FloatLayout:        
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_A
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_a/a.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_B
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_b/b.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_C
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_c/c.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_D
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_d/d.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_E
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_e/e.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_F
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_f/f.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_G
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_g/g.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_H
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_h/h.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_I
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_i/i.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_J
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_j/j.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_K
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_k/k.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_L
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_l/l.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_M
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_m/m.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_N
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_n/n.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_NN
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_ñ/ñ.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_O
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_o/o.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_P
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_p/p.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_Q
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_q/q.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_R
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_r/r.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_S
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_s/s.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_T
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_t/t.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_U
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_u/u.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_V
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_v/v.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_W
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_w/w.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
                
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_X
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_x/x.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_Y
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_y/y.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
    
        BubblePop:
            id: bubble_Z
            center: self.parent.center
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    source: 'data/img/letra_z/z.png'
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
```

[The "Z" bubble is always stationary in that corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPIvW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide bubbles by setting their opacity to zero or by positioning them offscreen.

All your bubbles from `C` to `Z` are in the same location, so you only see the last one drawn, which is `Z`.

Comment: But if I initialize in the .kv each bubble with an off-screen position, the bubbles "A" and "B" also disappear